# Editor Placeholder Error

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to add search capability to a table view controller.

I am getting an error saying I have an editor placeholder in my source code. It is in the `updateSearchResults` method where I am implementing the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol.
Here is the code generating this error:

```
   import UIKit
    class SearchTable : UITableViewController {     
    }

    extension SearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            }

}
```

I have not implemented this method just yet but will later - I am just wondering why this error is surfacing as I have provided the stub for the method and will return to it later?

Comment: Is there any placeholder text (highlighted background) in there?

Comment: I deleted it - it was just the placeholder saying "code". I deleted it and the error persisted. Then I added some more code just now just above the extension inside the class body, and the error moved upwards to there and again no placeholder text. I did a Build, and it went away. I think it just lingered from the earlier code placeholder text. Kinda odd?

Comment: make sure you have got error after run

Comment: @cheznead That's a common problem with Xcode, sometimes after you've fixed a problem you'll still need to rebuild or sometimes even clear the build before it recognizes it.

Comment: The fresh build worked this time at least! What do you mean by clear the build though? Do you mean run it after?